# can't install py2app because it has no __main__ routine

Tags: py2app

I have downloaded py2app tar, unzipped it and and am trying to install it on an off-line pc, so I can't use easy_install.

I opened a console window and typed:

C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py D:\py2app\ install (because D:\py2app\ is where the setup.py file is in the py2app extracted files.

the problem is I got an error saying can't find 'main' module in d:\py2app.  and I checked it out, there is no **main** routine anywhere in the py2app setup.py file.

So what do I do now to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install py2app on a Windows PC and that won't work anyway because py2app is mac specific and cannot cross "compile".

In general disutils/setuptools (and setup.py scripts) assume that setup.py is located in the current working directory, so even when py2app did support Windows you couldn't install it this way.

The correct way to install a python package:

```
D:\> cd D:\py2app
D:\py2app\> C:\python27\python.exe setup.py install
```

But again, py2app won't work on Windows.

Comment: so I have to install Python and Py2app on a Mac and do the conversion there?